# XML - XSL stylesheet problems

Tags: xml, xslt

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="vehicles.xsl"?>

<!-- File Name : vehicles.xml -->

<data>
    <params>
        <returned_page>1</returned_page>
        <total_pages>6</total_pages>
        <items_count>56</items_count>
        <previous_page></previous_page>
        <next_page>2</next_page>
    </params>
    <grid>
        <row>
            <car_id>1</car_id>
            <car_name>Audi A1</car_name>
            <car_price_per_day>75.33</car_price_per_day >
            <car_availability>1</car_availability>
        </row>
        <row>
            <car_id>2</car_id>
            <car_name>IQ 30</car_name>
            <car_price_per_day>45.99</car_price_per_day >
            <car_availability>1</car_availability>
        </row>
        <row>
            <car_id>3</car_id>
            <car_name>BMW 320</car_name>
            <car_price_per_day>86.44</car_price_per_day >
            <car_availability>0</car_availability>
        </row>
        <row>
            <car_id>4</car_id>
            <car_name>Ford Fiesta</car_name>
            <car_price_per_day >54.68</car_price_per_day>
            <car_availability>0</car_availability>
        </row>
        <row>
            <car_id>5</car_id>
            <car_name>Volkswagen Scirocco</car_name>
            <car_price_per_day >65.99</car_price_per_day >
            <car_available >0</car_available >
        </row>
    </grid>
</data>





 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="htp://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- File Name : vehicles.xsl -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>CARS</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price/Day</th>
                    <th>Availability</th>
                </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="row">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_id"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_name"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_price_per_day"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_availability"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

none of my explorers open the stylesheet..cant find what wrong with it i tried another encoding, full path to "value-of select" commands, "data" and "rows" as template match but same output.
i have tried ie, mozila firefox and google chrome
chrome gives me a blank page, ie the xml file in a single row and firefox "Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed."
any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Your xslt starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="htp://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

and ends with

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which does not match the opening tag.

The opening tag also has a typo in the transform URI.

If you change the start to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

There is no longer an error in running the stylesheet.

With this much fixing however, it still does not work properly because the line

```
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
```

finds no rows.  This is because the "row" tag is not immediately under the root.

Changing this to

```
        <xsl:for-each select="data/grid/row">
```

makes your transform work at least for the data shown.

There may be other improvements to be made, but this should get you to the point of having a functional transform.

The entire transform with these changes is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- File Name : vehicles.xsl -->

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h2>CARS</h2>
            <table border="1">
                <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Price/Day</th>
                    <th>Availability</th>
                </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="data/grid/row">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_id"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_name"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_price_per_day"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="car_availability"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using xsltproc to test it produces sensible output, and for me it also looks fine in Firefox 17.0.1.

Comment: u are right i forgot to change stylesheet to transform in end tag.. but again with both tags stylesheet or transform same problem i have

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but still same problem -.- i tried full paths to match, value-of, for-each commands

Comment: so its something wrong with my pc?? cause 3 explorers cant be wrong

Comment: Also i just noticed ie dont give access to a program called activeX..is this essential?

Comment: I don't know of the interaction between activeX and XSLT in IE.  It shouldn't matter, but it might.  Hard for me to tell on my Mac...

Comment: That was the uri fix I mentioned.  Was it somewhere else too?